# Can heap size be increased on Neo4j community edition

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j community edition. I am using 150 nodes and every node has a relationship with the other.

When I am running a query it throws an error:

```
Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError
```

How can I increase the heap size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. Just edit your `neo4j.conf` file. Take a look at [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#heap-sizing):

> The heap memory size is determined by the parameters in
>   `NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`, namely `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size` and
>   `dbms.memory.heap.max_size providing` the heap size in Megabytes or with
>   a unit, e.g. 16000 or preferably 16G. It is recommended to set these
>   two parameters to the same value to avoid unwanted full garbage
>   collection pauses.

Comment: In the config file, there is no such thing as dbms.memory.heap.initial_size and  dbms.memory.heap.max_size. I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Neo4j docs talk it about your error (Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError): _There is not enough stack size to perform the current task. This is generally considered to be a database error, so please contact Neo4j support. You could try increasing the stack size: for example to set the stack size to 2M, add `dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss2M' to in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation just add -Xss2M as command line flag._

Comment: https://neo4j.com/editions/ this link says that limited memory for community edition. The above commands work for enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm using desktop version I couldn't find on UI